# How to prevent to visit login page if user is logged in

Tags: reactjs, session, redirect, navigation

How can I prevent to visit login page if user is logged in, I don't want to show user login page if user if user is not logged out. but I have tried with few step but it is not working for me.

I am storing static value in localstorage and if user try to come back into page login page then there I have created a function that user can visit to login page or not

login.js

```
  componentWillMount(){
  var id = localstorage.getitem('id')
  if(id == "1"){
     return <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>

  }
}
```

Here I am able to get it and it going inside if condition as well but not redirecting to dashboard
                    I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Your help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) works only when it is rendered, which means it is inside `render` or one of the functions called by it.

Returning a `Redirect` inside `componentDidMount` does not redirect the user. For use inside `componentDidMount`, you can use the imperative API:

```
this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
```

[Docs for `history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

Note that this works only if the component is directly rendered inside a `Route`, otherwise props `history` will not be present. In other case, you can use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher order component.

Comment: ok, but do  you have any idea how can I prevent to visit login page if user is not logged out?

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga Add a redirect there too.